# doseResponse function MATLAB iteration limit exceeded warning

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, sigmoid

I've been running a variation of the doseResponse function downloaded from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33604-doseresponse) to generate dose-response sigmoid curves. However, I've had trouble with one of my datasets generating a linear curve instead. By running the following code, I get the following error and produce the following graph. I also uploaded the data called dose2.csv and resp2.csv to google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FG2YfgF-5KDyhYQhazJBP6WH4m-6DhLT?usp=sharing). Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks.

Code to generate graph

```
% Plotting Dose-Response Curve
response = resp2;
dose = dose2; 

% Deal with 0 dosage by using it to normalise the results.
normalised=0;
if (sum(dose(:)==0)>0)
    %compute mean control response
    controlResponse=mean(response(dose==0));
    %remove controls from dose/response curve
    response=response(dose~=0)/controlResponse;
    dose=dose(dose~=0);
    normalised=1;
end

%hill equation sigmoid
sigmoid=@(beta,x)beta(1)+(beta(2)-beta(1))./(1+(x/beta(3)).^beta(4));

%calculate some rough guesses for initial parameters
minResponse=min(response);
maxResponse=max(response);
midResponse=mean([minResponse maxResponse]);
minDose=min(dose);
maxDose=max(dose);

%fit the curve and compute the values
%[coeffs,r,J]=nlinfit(dose,response,sigmoid,[minResponse maxResponse midResponse 1]); % nlinfit doesn't work as well
beta_new = lsqcurvefit(sigmoid,[minResponse maxResponse midResponse 1],dose,response);
[coeffs,r,J]=nlinfit(dose,response,sigmoid, beta_new);

ec50=coeffs(3);
hillCoeff=coeffs(4);

%plot the fitted sigmoid
xpoints=logspace(log10(minDose),log10(maxDose),1000);
semilogx(xpoints,sigmoid(coeffs,xpoints),'Color',[1 0 0],'LineWidth',2)
hold on

%notate the EC50
text(ec50,mean([coeffs(1) coeffs(2)]),[' \leftarrow ' sprintf('EC_{50}=%0.2g',ec50)],'FontSize',20,'Color',[1 0 0]);

%plot mean response for each dose with standard error
doses=unique(dose);
meanResponse=zeros(1,length(doses));
stdErrResponse=zeros(1,length(doses));
for i=1:length(doses)
    responses=response(dose==doses(i));
    meanResponse(i)=mean(responses);
    stdErrResponse(i)=std(responses)/sqrt(length(responses));
    %stdErrResponse(i)=std(responses);
end

errorbar(doses,meanResponse,stdErrResponse,'o','Color',[1 0 0],'LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',12)
```

Warning Message

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

lsqcurvefit stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 4.000000e+02.

Warning: Iteration limit exceeded.  Returning results from final iteration.
```

Graph (looking to generate a sigmoid curve not linear)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to optimize your initial value `[minResponse maxResponse midResponse 1]` for `lsqcurvefit`. Don't just simply start with minimum or maximum values of given values. Instead, you may first start with your equations to estimate your coefficients.

Given the sigmoid model of `sigmoid=@(beta,x)beta(1)+(beta(2)-beta(1))./(1+(x/beta(3)).^beta(4))`. As `x` gets arbitrarily close to `inf`, equation will return `beta(2)`. And as `x` gets arbitrarily close to `0`, equation will return `beta(1)`. Therefore, initial estimation of `minResponse`, `maxResponse`, and `midResponse` seems reasonable enough. Actually your problem lies in your initial estimation of `1`. `beta(4)` can be roughly estimated with the inclination of your log graph. To my rough sketch it was around 1/4 and therefore you may conclude that your initial estimation of 1 was too large for convergence.

```
beta_new = lsqcurvefit(sigmoid,[minResponse maxResponse midResponse 1/4],dose,response);
```

[image: Revised]